# How to make each unique observation a factor w/ a binary response in R?

Tags: r, loops, refactoring

I have a data set like:

```
id   region
 1     2
 1     3
 2     1
 3     4
 3     5
```

I want to create a data set like:

```
id   region1 region2 region3 region4 region5
 1     0         1      1       0      0
 2     1         0      1       0      0
 3     0         0      0       1      1
```

I have been using a handwritten loop that creates a factor regionN each time, but am hoping there is someway to automate this process.

I have also tried the following which fails.

```
n <- 1
while(n <= nrow(region_list))  {
  paste("R",as.character(region_list$region_id[n])) <- subset(region_list, region_list$region_id == n)
  n <- n + 1
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DF <- data.frame(id = c(1,1,2,3,3), region = c(2,3,1,4,5))
DM <- table(DF)
DM
#   region
#id  1 2 3 4 5
#  1 0 1 1 0 0
#  2 1 0 0 0 0
#  3 0 0 0 1 1
is.matrix(DM)
#[1] TRUE

require(reshape)
DF2 <- cast(data.frame(DM),id~region)
names(DF2)[-1] <- paste("region",names(DF2)[-1],sep="")
DF2
#  id region1 region2 region3 region4 region5
#1  1       0       1       1       0       0
#2  2       1       0       0       0       0
#3  3       0       0       0       1       1
```

Comment: Thanks @Roland. It looks like I might have needed to do: DF2 <- data.frame(cast(data.frame(DM),id~region)). Does that makes sense? Also, the variable names I was getting were in the format: regionX1. Is there a way to get rid of the X easily?

Comment: One more question: For a similar table, but for which the id's repeat, what value argument do I use to just put a (1) or a (0) instead of frequency?  <Using Freq as value column.  Use the value argument to cast to override this choice>

Comment: No, that does not make sense, since `cast`returns a data.frame. The X are introduced by `data.frame`'s `check.names` function, so you might need to set `check.names = FALSE` in one of your calls to `data.frame`. However, I cannot reproduce without more information. I do not understand your second comment. Maybe you should ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

This solution uses `ddply` form **plyr** but any similar split-apply-combine tool will work with the same basic pieces:

```
dat <- read.table(text = "id   region
 1     2
 1     3
 2     1
 3     4
 3     5",header = TRUE,sep = "",stringsAsFactors = TRUE)

dat$region <- factor(dat$region)

foo <- function(x){
    res <- as.integer(levels(x$region) %in% x$region)
    names(res) <- paste0("region",1:5)
    res
}

ddply(dat,.(id),.fun = foo)
   id region1 region2 region3 region4 region5
1  1       0       1       1       0       0
2  2       1       0       0       0       0
3  3       0       0       0       1       1
```

You could get around converting `region` to a factor, but then I think you'd have to hard code the possible unique values it could take inside of `foo`.

Comment: I'm sure this likely works as well, but the first response seemed easier for me to understand and replicate with the number of tables for which I need to perform this function.